# How do I add dynamic text to a HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS. I want to add (elements) words from an array on mouse click into HTML.

```js
var pos = document.querySelector('span');
for (let i = 0; i < array length; i++) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pos.innerHTML = array[i];
  });
}
```

```html
<p> the word generated is <span></span></p>
<button>go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ['1', '2', '3'];
var pos = document.getElementById('output');
var button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    pos.innerHTML = pos.innerHTML + array1[i];
  }
});
```

```html
<p>the word generated is <span id="output"></span></p>
<button id="btn">go</button>
```

This will display all element of array on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it randomly displays a word in `span` element.

```js
var words = ['rest', 'fever', 'ball', 'sky', 'earth', 'moon', 'sun', 'temper'];
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button').item(0);
button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
 let span = document.querySelectorAll('p span').item(0);
 let randomWord = words[Math.round(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))];
 span.textContent = randomWord;
});
```

```css
p span {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<p> the word generated is <span></span></p>
<button>go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Or with Jquery:**

```
<p> the word generated is <span></span></p>
<button id="btn">go</button>
```

Code:

```
var array = ['test','test2'];

  $('#btn).on('click', function () {
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
  $('p span).append(entry+' ');
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for random text generations, you can use random function to generate random array indexes.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pos.innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(arr.length))]
});
```